# Can't install local extension in Bolt CM

Tags: composer-php, silex, bolt-cms

I a trying to write an extension for Bolt CM. I decided I should start by just doing the tutorial they provide, although I can't get it to work. When viewed on the "Extend"-page in the CMS itself the extension shows up but does not work. Instead, it shows local/author/urlfield — [INVALID] — [DISABLED].

I'm quite sure that the problem is located in the extensions/composer.json file. I added the namespace of my extension to the "require" array (second from above):

```
"require": {
    "sahassar/gmaps": "^4.0",
    "myname/myexension": "^1.0",
    "larsvanscheijndel/urlfield": "^1.0",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.3"
}
```

If I change the name of the extension in this file, it changes in the CMS aswell.

I really can't find where to use namespaces, where to use file locations, and whether to use all lower case, camel case or any other type of casing.

Can anyone help? All input is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can call upon it in the local extension map?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, can't solve it so far.

Comment: Try to follow the tutorial of installing a local extension provided in the documentation. I had to do it over and over several times, ruining my build a few times. Eventually I got it to work. I must admit that doing it this way is kind of the opposite of straight forward, but if you do everything step by step it should work.

Comment: There are a lot of steps to get right. 

I've been battling with this and then realised that the url path in my /extensions/composer.json was wrong. 

I'm using a Vagrant box, and realised I was using the path to the repository on the host not the path in the vagrant box (where bolt was running) - so that is something to check.